Research Help Please - old Kodak camera
Back in the 1940s, my mom had a folding Kodak camera that featured photography without a lens! I'm trying to figure out what model it was and what film size it most likely used. (The camera itself is long gone, as the bellows developed holes from constant use.) I have no negatives to judge film size, just positive prints. The image part of the prints measure 2.5 by 4.25, but I have no idea whether the prints are contact or made in an enlarger of some kind.
Pictures I've seen of the Number 3 Folding Pocket Camera look very similar, but they all have glass lenses. This had no lens whatever, neither glass or plastic, just a small hole. You could see and even touch the shutter, right in or just behind the hole. The film size had three digits, and started with either 11 or 12. For example, 116 or. 118, or 127. It was NOT 120. The film had a red back paper, and numbers on the backing paper were in black on the red background, which you could see through a small red plastic circular window on the back, bottom margin, so you could tell how many pics you had taken. (I think the max was 8, but not sure.) The film spools were made of metal, not wood or plastic. When you completed a roll of film, you had to keep the spool that the roll had been wound on, and move it to be the take-up spool for the new roll.
It had a waist-level viewfinder mounted just to the left of the hole and shutter (as viewed from behind) which you could swivel by 90 degrees to accommodate either vertical or horizontal format. You could take time exposures using a T setting. There was a built-in self timer, if you wanted to get into your own picture. I don't remember shutter speeds or F-stops or anything like that.
Any thoughts?

The camera almost surely had some kind of lens. If it was a simple meniscus lens, it was likely behind the shutter. Many box cameras and some folders appear to lack a lens at first glance because of this arrangement.
Kodak made many 116 cameras which could fit the bill. Check out the various No. 1A folders and see if any of these are the one you remember. I suspect it's a 116 camera, since the negatives are 2.5x4.25", which would give you contact prints of that size.

yes, for photography to work, an image needs to be projected onto the image plane, and the only way you can do this is by using a lens...or a pinhole. A hole big enough for your finger will not project any image onto the image plane by itself - hence there must have been a lens.

Sounds like the model B (Hawkeye 2A) 116 cartridge camera; the lens is behind the shutter.

The Hawkeye 2A model B is indeed it. Thanks so much.
